# HtmlAgilityPack - How to extract data?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How to get 1988 from the following HTML using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
<span class="year">Year: <strong class="">1988</strong></span>
```

I tried with:

```
.Descendants("span").Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("year")).First().Attributes["strong"].DeEntitizeValue;
```

but null value is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `InnerText` of the strong element.
In your example you could do just

```
SelectSingleNode("//strong").InnerText
```

Modify the `strong` selector appropriatelly for you use case.

[Documentation here](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-single-node)

Comment: Great, thanks. What do I do in case there are multiple <strong> elements in the HTML document?

Comment: In your example you can do `//span[@class=year]/strong`. Otherwise it depends on your particular use case. Lear how to use a XPath.